# how to showing plugin comment fb on angular js?

Tags: angularjs, facebook, plugins, comments

i'm new on angular, and i have some problem to showing plugin comment fb on my angular web app.

i following this tutorial : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/TLLFg/)

example code :

```
// preview.directive.js :

'use strict';

window.FB = {
    XFBML: {
        parse: function (elem) {
            var pre = document.createElement('pre');
            pre.textContent = elem.innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('fb-comment-box').innerHTML =
                    pre.outerHTML;
        }
    }
};

angular.module('kulinerLezatkuApp')
  .directive('myFbCommentBox', function () {
    function createHTML(href, numposts, colorscheme) {
        return '<div class="fb-comments" ' +
                       'data-href="' + href + '" ' +
                       'data-numposts="' + numposts + '" ' +
                       'data-colorsheme="' + colorscheme + '">' +
               '</div>';
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('pageHref', function (newValue) {
                var href        = newValue;
                var numposts    = attrs.numposts    || 5;
                var colorscheme = attrs.colorscheme || 'light';

                elem.html(createHTML(href, numposts, colorscheme));
                FB.XFBML.parse(elem[0]);
            });
        }
    };
});

// preview.html
<div id="fb-comment-box" my-fb-comment-box=""
            page-href="http://localhost:9000/items/{{main.myParams._id}}/preview"
            numposts="5"
            colorsheme="light">
```

but on my page just showing text, and not html...i need help thanks

====================

## Solved with [easyfb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-easyfb)

Comment: *my page just showing text, and not html* I'm not sure what this means. Are you expecting the actual HTML code to be visible on the page?

Comment: the directive just return my html as text on my view, i wish get html from my directive @BSMP

Comment: In [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/TLLFg/) appended **html** into **pre** tag. What you achieve?

Comment: how to showing plugin comment fb as html on directive @StepanKasyanenko ?

Comment: Update your question, add the desired result in the form of **html**.

Comment: solved, i'm using easyfb...thanks